# iPad App running slow and after some time crashed

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, profiling, instruments

On a button tap about 60 plus times My iPad App getting slow and then finally crashed

On Start my app is working just Perfect, after some time its getting slow and more slow....

**it takes about 8 to 10 seconds to respond the action, and finally it is crashed**
 I don't know why this all is happening.
 I am using a collectionview on uiviewcontroller, all its content views are created in custome cell class.

**after using Instruments to test on iPAd 2, took these screen shoots.**

now what should I do.?? have you seen any problem here...???

**here is Plus button in UICollectionView Cell to perform an action, on button tap time is increasing randomly and reached to 300000+ ms**

Note that ---> Main thread shows 0.0 ms

What that mean....????

please guide me in right direction

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

this is code what I am doing in these methods on button tap

```
 // 'purchasedProduct' is NSMutuableDictionary    

-(void)btnPlus:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    indexPaths   = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];        
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:myCollection];
    btnIndex = [myCollection indexPathForItemAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[myCollection cellForItemAtIndexPath:btnIndex];
    NSString *newCode = [productID objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row];
    newQty = cell.cellQty.text;
    newQty = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[newQty integerValue] + 1];
    BOOL currentCellHasUpdates = purchasedProduct[newCode] != nil;
    if (currentCellHasUpdates)
    {
        // Object Already Exist.......
        [purchasedProduct setObject:newQty  forKey:newCode];
        prdID = newCode;
        [self UpdateProduct];
    }
    else
    {
        // create new object........
        [purchasedProduct setObject:newQty  forKey:newCode];
        prdID = newCode;
        [self BuyProduct];
    }
    [indexPaths addObject:btnIndex];
    [myCollection reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths]; // I think problem is here.
}
```

CellForItemAtIndexPath Method is

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
[[cell cellBtnPlus] addTarget:self action:@selector( btnPlus:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[[cell cellBtnMinus] addTarget:self action:@selector(btnMinus:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

BOOL currentCellHasUpdates = purchasedProduct[[productID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] != nil;
if (currentCellHasUpdates)
{
    cell.cellQty.text = [purchasedProduct objectForKey: [productID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.cellQty.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
else
{
    cell.cellQty.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    cell.cellQty.text = @"0";
}

image = nil;    
NSString *imageName =[[productID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath]];

if (image.size.width == image.size.height)
{
    //set newSize
}
if (image.size.width < image.size.height)
{
    //calculate newSize
}
else
{
    //calculate newSize
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
if (image.size.width == image.size.height)
{
    //set imgRect
}
if (image.size.width < image.size.height)
{
    //Calculations for imgRect
}
if (image.size.width > image.size.height)
{
    //Calculations for imgRect
}
cell.myImageView.frame = imgRect;
cell.myImageView.image = image;

cell.lbl1.text = [[desc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  capitalizedString];
cell.lbl2.text = [@"Box Qty:" stringByAppendingString:[boxQty objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.lbl4.text = [[code objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] uppercaseString];
cell.lbl5.text = [@"Pack Qty:" stringByAppendingString:[packQty objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

BOOL isStarProduct = starProducts[[productID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] != nil;
if (isStarProduct)
{
    cell.lbl6.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"]];
}
else
{
    cell.lbl6.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

return cell;
}
```

I think problem is at **reload on specific index paths in CollectionView** is causing the problem as it takes 91% of time to execute. am I right..???

**EDIT 2**

```
-(void)BuyProduct
{
newDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
currentDate = [formatter stringFromDate:newDate];

database = [dBName UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(database, &dbConnection) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqliteQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO ShopingCart"
                   " (fld1 , fld2, fld3, fld4, fld5, fld6, fld7, fld8, fld9, fld10, fld11, fld12, fld13, fld14, fld15, fld16)"
                   " VALUES (\'%d\', \"%@\", \'%d\', \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%f\", \"%f\", \"%@\", \"%@\","
                   " \"%@\", \"%f\", \"%.4f\", \'%d\', \'%d\', \'%d\')",
                   1,
                   currentDate,
                   91,
                   customerID,
                   [productID objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row],
                   [costPrice objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row],
                   [[price objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row] floatValue] * [newQty integerValue],
                   [[salePrice objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row] floatValue] * [newQty integerValue],
                   [qty objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row],
                   newQty,
                   [taxRate objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row],
                   [[price objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row] floatValue] * [newQty integerValue],
                   [[price objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row] floatValue] * [newQty integerValue] + [taxAmount floatValue],
                   0,
                   0,
                   0];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbConnection, [sqliteQuery UTF8String], -1, &sQLStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(sQLStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Inserted into Shopping Cart");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(sQLStatement);
    }

    sqliteQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT SUM(NetPrice) As TotalAmount"
                   " FROM ShopingCart WHERE CustomerID = \'%@\'",customerID];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbConnection, [sqliteQuery UTF8String], -1, &sQLStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(sQLStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sQLStatement, 0)];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(sQLStatement);
    }
    ordAmount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total £ %.2f",[temp floatValue]];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error %s ", sqlite3_errmsg(dbConnection));
}
sqlite3_close(dbConnection);
}
```

Where should / can I improve my code?

Comment: Your issue is the cellForRow method. Include that code. Instruments is clearly highlighting it as the main issue

Comment: @DanielGalasko you mean cellForItemAtIndexPath method??

Comment: @DanielGalasko plz chek this method. i have update the post

Comment: Ok, I'm posting an answer, won't be long

Comment: @DanielGalasko please check my updated question with use of dictionary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58791/discussion-between-daniel-galasko-and-zaibi).

Comment: @DanielGalasko please update your answer with this... [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
[collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
} completion:nil]; this is just perfect line of code. it solved the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instruments is clearly indicating `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:` as being the culprit for the experienced poor performance. This means that the collection view is taking a long time to dequeue cells.

Looking at your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method your for loop seems to be an attractive bet for where your performance is being affected. For each cell you are iterating through an array of products hoping to satisfy the following condition

```
if ([[productID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:[updatedCodes objectAtIndex:i]])
{
    cell.cellQty.text = [updatedQty objectAtIndex:i];
    cell.cellQty.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

Once this condition is true you update the cell, however you are not breaking out of the loop!

This means that for every cell you are iterating through the whole array! What you should be doing is placing a break statement inside the if to break out of the loop.

That being said I think we can get better. Given that you have an array of productIDs and an array of updatedCodes, you really should consider matching these with a Dictionary. Dictionaries are a great way of fetching objects by a particular key. Think of an array as being a dictionary where the key is the array index. So when you fetch an object at index 0, you are actually fetching the object whose key is 0. So in your example naturally the productID could be your key and the value will be the product. This will allow you to fetch any product instantly if you know its corresponding productID.

So you will need a dictionary containing all of your products. Then you will need a dictionary containing all of your updated codes. You could have the collection view display all the products from your dictionary(NSDictionary has the method "allValues") or you could have an array of products.

So the basic idea of what you need is:

1. Array of all products to display in collection view (lets call this productsArray).
2. Dictionary of products keyed by productID - `NSDictionary *productsKeyedByID = [NSDictionary dictionaryWitObjects:productsArray forKeys:[productsArray valueForKey:@"productID"]];\\where productID is a property on the product object`
3. Dictionary of updated products. This will be modified when items are updated.

The motivation behind this approach is to allow you to access a product or an updated product quickly based on a particular productID. This means that for every single product in the array, you can immediately check if it exists in the updated products dictionary.

So in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: you can have

```
MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
[[cell cellBtnPlus] addTarget:self action:@selector( btnPlus:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[[cell cellBtnMinus] addTarget:self action:@selector(btnMinus:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

NSString *currentCellProductId = productsArray[indexPath.row];
//using the modern syntax - you could also use the objectForKey: method.
BOOL currentCellHasUpdates = updatedCodesKeyedByID[currentCellProductId] != nil;
if (currentCellHasUpdates) {
    cell.cellQty.text = updatedCodesKeyedByID[currentCellProductId].quantity;
    cell.cellQty.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
} else {
    cell.cellQty.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    cell.cellQty.text = @"0";
}
```

Now in your handling of the button tap you can also leverage the power of dictionaries:

```
-(void)btnPlus:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:myCollection];
    btnIndex = [myCollection indexPathForItemAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[myCollection cellForItemAtIndexPath:btnIndex];
    NSString *newCode = [productID objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row];
    newQty = cell.cellQty.text;
    if (updatedCodesKeyedByID[newCode] != nil)
    {
        //NSLog(@"Object Already Exist...");
         id codeToUpdate = updatedCodesKeyedByID[newCode];
         codeToUpdate.quantity++;
         [self UpdateProduct]; // Open DB SQlite DB Connection and update Table Record and Close Connection.
      } 
      else
      {
           updatedCodesKeyedByID[newCode] = //create new object
           [self BuyProduct]; // Open DB SQlite DB Connection and update Table Record and Close Connection.
      }
 }
```

**NOTE** You may want to consider changing your design to have only one Dictionary containing products and each product has an associated quantity. This will default to 0 when not set. This way you only need to check one Dictionary and it seems to fulfill what you are doing in this post; namely updating the quantity on an item.

**EDIT** after moving this discussion to the chat, the final piece to the puzzle was to call UICollectionView's reloadItemsAtIndexPaths: inside of a performBatchUpdates block.

Comment: i have replaced Arrays with dictionay. test in simulator Time Profiler but it looks just like before it was increasing the time randomly. i have not my iPad at this time so test in Simulator.

Comment: And if you comment out your image code? Seems like you are doing a lot of complex image drawing. Have you removed the for loop inside your cell for row?

Comment: I'm also not sure what you are doing in your UpdateProduct and SellProduct methods

Comment: in these two methods i just open SQlite3 DB Connection and update DB Records then finally close DB Connection.

Comment: I hope you making this calls asynchronously... Also, you should consider familiarizing yourself with Core Data. Its Apples built in object persistence framework that is super brilliant for storing and retrieving objects (its backed by SQL). Again, take out your image code in cellForRow and see if that makes a difference

Comment: i just tried with comment out the whole image code in cell for Row Method. Use Time Profiler but still its taking 89% of time in reload CollectionView.

Comment: change this - [myCollection reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths]; to this [myCollection reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[btnIndex]];

Comment: Please Check BuyProduct Method Code.

Comment: My suspicion is that you are calling reloadItems with an array that is increasing all the time (so don't store the array of buttonIndexes). You are also performing all your SQL on the main thread, another performance hit (Consider using Core Data or you can use an NSOperationQueue to place your updates in a background thread).

Comment: [myCollection reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[btnIndex]]; tried with this too. but no luck :(

Comment: So if you remove all the data base code is it still as slow? I would recommend doing another profile so you can better see the point of failure.

Comment: i also tried to perform BuyProduct Method in Background thread as [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(BuyProduct) withObject:nil]; but again no luck ... :(

Comment: I wouldn't use the performSelectorInBackground you really should consider using either an operation queue or core data. Maintaining your own SQL stack is a lot of work and maintaining upgrades and cascading deletion is a lot of work. That being said i can't help until i know exactly where your performance is being hit...

Comment: in simulator it not running slow but time profiler showed me more than 88 % time usage. but in iPad it is running slow and slow and  finally crashed

Comment: Yes and if you drill down is all that time in the reload method?

Comment: I'm asking that if you use instruments again. is all the time still being spent in reloadItemsAtIndexPaths

Comment: Yes instruments again showed me all the time is being spent on reloadItemsAtIndexPaths

Comment: i tried with commenting the BuyProduct and UpdateProduct Methods, just update dictionary value on button tap and reload CollectionView Single Cell. but again instruments showed 90% time is being spent by reload CollectionView Cell at specific IndexPath.
and CellForItemAtIndexPath doesn't contain the image code this time.